Cross-chain NFT transfer with CCIP local simulator (Foundry) - DestinationchainNotAllowlisted error
I'm facing an error while attempting to transfer a minted NFT cross-chain using the CCIP local simulator (via Foundry) and paying the fee with native cryptocurrency (ETH).
The problem:
* I think here able to successfully send the NFT, as message ID is generated.

* However, the receiver side encounters an error while sending the acknowledgement (ACK).

* The error message is "DestinationchainNotAllowlisted" (see Screenshot 1). 

Screenshots:
Screenshot 1: Error message "DestinationchainNotAllowlisted"

Screenshot 2: (You can see allowlistDestinationchain is successfuly been set)

Screenshot 3: (Optional, if relevant)


    

Contradiction:
The test script code (https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/test/gameX.t.sol#L529) in Screenshot 2 appears to whitelist the destination chain successfully.
Request for Help:
I'm unsure why this error persists. If you'd like to replicate the scenario, follow these steps:
1) Clone the repository: https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/tree/main
2) Run forge build
3) Run tests with extended output: forge test --match-path test/gameX.t.sol -vvv
4) Look for the test case "testCCIPFunctionality()" in gameX.t.sol (Line 521)

Relevant Contract Files:
1) RPG.sol (Main NFT contract for source chain): https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/RPG.sol

2) RPG_RECEIVER.sol (Main NFT contract for destination chain): https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/RPG_RECEIVER.sol 

3) IRPG.sol (Interface for RPG.sol): https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/IRPG.sol

4) ccip_rpg_sender.sol: https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/ccip_rpg_sender.sol (CCIP router contract for sending messages)

5) ccip_rpg_receiver.sol: https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/ccip_rpg_receiver.sol (CCIP router contract for receiving messages)


RPGItemUtils.sol: https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/src/RPGItemUtils.sol (supporting RPG extra functions)
The only difference between

RPG.sol and RPG_RECEIVER.sol is the _ccipHandler address.
RPG.sol (source chain): _ccipHandler = 0xF62849F9A0B5Bf2913b396098F7c7019b51A820a
RPG_RECEIVER.sol (destination chain):_ccipHandler =[![enter image description here][1]][1] 0x5991A2dF15A8F6A256D3Ec51E99254Cd3fb576A9

These addresses were obtained by console logging address(ccipRpgSender) and address(ccipRpgReceiver)
(https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/test/gameX.t.sol#L78).
Note: 1)this contract worked on avlanche and ether sapolio testnet (via faucet test tokens)

Also cross transfer of NFT sucessfully executed on forked testnet environmnet:

https://github.com/sauravs/gameX_contract_testing/blob/main/test/gameXForked.t.sol
You can verify it by running:
forge test --match-path test/gameXForked.t.sol -vvv

I'm trying to reproduce the error, but unable to find this folder lib/ccip/contracts/src/v0.8/vendor/openzeppelin-solidity/v4.8.3/contracts/. I can see this being added to remappings @chainlink/contracts-ccip/=lib/ccip/contracts/, but the compiler is unable to find that.

Please after cloning the repo ,replace the "lib" folder with the lib folder provided
in this link "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ooW9ViDm9q1PI41ztcOZn2tvMYX9D7AF"
It should work

I've requested the access of the folder on drive. Please check.

Given ,pls check

You need to allowlist the destination chain from the CCIP_RPG_RECEIVER contract as well, because in the _ccipReceive of the same, you're calling sendAcknowledgement which is sending message (as acknowledgement) back to the CCIP_RPG_SENDER contract.
So, add this in your testCCIPFunctionality test function:
ccipRpgReceiver.allowlistDestinationChain(chainSelector, true);

But, after that, you would face NotEnoughGasForCall error, particularly due to the router.ccipSend call in the sendAcknowledgement function of the CCIP_RPG_RECEIVER contract, and that error is persistent even after funding the CCIP_RPG_RECEIVER contract with enough ether, using:
vm.deal(address(ccipRpgReceiver), 100 ether);

So, I'm still debugging that. Just updating you, so that you can also try debugging the same by doing the changes on your end.

thanks for the point out.
You dont need to fund CCIP_RPG_RECEIVER seprately.
Fee will be cut directly from External account (whoever will be calling) transferNFT function .
Please add {value: 10 ether} while calling  ccipRpgSender.transferNft function as it is payable.
I missed that earlier.You can check inside gameXForked.t.sol.
         ccipRpgSender.transferNft{value: 100 ether}(             0, address(rpg), address(rpg_receiver), chainSelector, address(ccipRpgReceiver)         );

it is still not working though even while sending 100 ethers along with this transfer

Yes, I did that too. But, still facing NotEnoughGasForCall error. I've even tried increasing the gasLimit for ccipSend that you've set in the constructor as 900_000.

I think we need to figure out who is making the call to that particular ccipSend inside sendAcknowledgement which is going as underfunded. As per the flow, it should be ccipRpgReceiver, but even after funding that (or not as it's getting charged from the value passed while calling transferNft), it's still showing as underfunded.
